# How to use cpp-netlib with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, http, boost, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to use cpp-netlib with Visual Studio 2010.
I've built cpp-netlib and add .lib files to my project, but I can't compile them.

--Environment

- Windows 7 x64
- cpp-netlib 0.11.0
- boost 1.55.0
- Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1f

My code is here.

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace boost::network;

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [url]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    http::client client;
    http::client::request request(argv[1]);
    request << header("Connection", "close");
    http::client::response response = client.get(request);
    std::cout << body(response) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I added the cpp-netlib library path and the cpp-netlib include path to the project.
Boost and openssl paths were also added.
I added the libs to the project.

- libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- cppnetlib-client-connections.lib
- cppnetlib-uri.lib

I think the errors come from something related OpenSSL.

```
Error   55  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - function _BIO_ctrl ...
```

Actually, I have Japanese one so it's like below.

```
エラー 55  error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル _BIO_ctrl が関数 "public: class boost::system::error_code const & __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::map_error_code(class boost::system::error_code &)const " (?map_error_code@engine@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QBEABVerror_code@system@5@AAV675@@Z) で参照されました。    cppnetlib-client-connections.lib(client.obj)    
エラー 57  error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル _BIO_ctrl_pending が関数 "private: enum boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::want __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::perform(int (__thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::*)(void *,unsigned int),void *,unsigned int,class boost::system::error_code &,unsigned int *)" (?perform@engine@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@AAE?AW4want@12345@P812345@AEHPAXI@Z0IAAVerror_code@system@5@PAI@Z) で参照されました。    cppnetlib-client-connections.lib(client.obj)
エラー 43  error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル _BIO_free が関数 "public: __thiscall boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::~engine(void)" (??1engine@detail@ssl@asio@boost@@QAE@XZ) で参照されました。    cppnetlib-client-connections.lib(client.obj)
```

Could you tell me what I'm missing?
I tried to add more libs to the project, but it still didn't work.

Comment: `BIO_ctrl()` and friends are indeed part of OpenSSL. Did you add that library to your linker settings?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't add the OpenSSL libraries to it. I passed error when I add libeay and ssleay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've got to add these two library.

libeay32.lib
ssleay32.lib

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, except i fixed it by using the WIN32 version of SSL instead of the X64 version.